# flutter how can i cast String to TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, casting, controller, texteditingcontroller

hi i'm looking for a way to cast String variable into TextEditingController

```
  final TextEditingController _testController=TextEditingController();
```

and this is what i'm doing

```
var test = "_"+"testController"
```

and inside `TextFormField` `Controller` i'm calling controller like this

```
TextFormField(
controller: test,
),
```

I know i could've just called it by the name of `TextEditingController` `_testController` but i have to do it this way, any ideas how ? i tried `casting` the `variable` to `TextEditingController` but i get this error saying that

```
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'TextEditingController' in type cast
```

Comment: Do you want your _testController's text to be the string inside test variable?

Comment: no i want to call the controller which name is _testController by a string variable var test='_testController '

Comment: So basically yo want to determine the controller based on the test variable? you cannot cast it but you can create a method to return a controller based on the text

Comment: just a basic switch case, right ? no need for extension method ?

Comment: I think a simple switch statement would be enough.

Comment: i think it's better if i made an extension method since i have 28 TextEditingController, i'm wondering if you could help me implement the method since I'm not very familiar of it's implementation, please

Comment: Consider creating a Map or a List with all those TextEditingControllers.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in the comments you have 28 TextEditingControllers.

You could get access to the right one by creating a Map.

```
var test = "_"+"testController"
final TextEditingController _testController=TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController _nameController=TextEditingController(); //Second controller

Map<String, TextEditingController> textMap = {'_testController': _testController, '_nameController': _nameController}; //Map declaration
```

and then use it as:

```
    TextFormField(
     controller: textMap[test], //Access to the right controller by String Key
     ),
```